# Turnoff a-la-carte (treeshaking) in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetify-loader

I am writing a custom vuetify components-based library.
when i try to build and install to another app it doesn't work. I struggle for few days and find out if the component define inside custom component and custom component call together it renders property.

This problem is based on vuetify treeshaking.

How to turnoff Treehaking (a-la-carte) in vuetify ?

Answer (score 0):

After few research i found that treeshaking is enable by default. you can turn off manually at the time of installation.

instead of using default component
[image: Select configuration on installing vuetify]

After few steps you find Use a-la-carte components? option.

[image: option to choose whether we require treeshaking or not]

By this way you can turnoff treeshaking in vuetify.